# Goodness of fit for two different properties of the same model?

Tags: error-analysis, statistics, models

This is a question about statistics and optimisation.

I have a model which produces two different distributions of the **same dimension.** Let's say they are the mean velocity distribution $\langle v(r) \rangle$ and the RMS velocity distribution $(\langle v^2(r) \rangle)^{1/2}$ of the system I am modelling, and **both are functions of the same variable $\mathbf{r}$**.

My model is **unscaled in the vertical direction.** That is, I can use some physical argument to set the scaling on the horizontal axis, in order to compare the model to real data. However I am free to choose the vertical scaling, in order to get the best possible goodness-of-fit statistic (let's say $\chi^2$ as a concrete example) for **both distributions simultaneously**. The datasets for each distribution have *different uncertainties*.

Both distributions are equally important to fit well.

My question is this: *How do I combine the $\chi^2$ values for two distributions produced by the **same model** in order to get the best possible scaling to suit both of these distributions? Is there a standard method for this?*

Comment: This question would be better suited to [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).